# read large text file into array with specific format

Tags: c#

I have a text file with the following format of information:

```
1 1.2323232 2.2356 4.232 1.23664  
2 1.344545  
3 6.2356 7.56455212   
etc....
```

How do I read the file in C#, parse it into an array, then do some processing on it?

Comment: at least have you tried to solve it?

Comment: post sample array with the required data. It is unclear if you want each row per array index or something different?

Comment: I don't know what is "large" to you. Depending of the size of your file, you better be careful about using memory to stock an array of all lines instead of processing sequences of it directly (like writing into db..).

Answer (score 1):

Use [File Helpers.](http://www.filehelpers.com)

For eg. All you would need is to define the record parsing as this :

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class Orders
{
   public int OrderID;

   public string CustomerID;
   [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy")]   public DateTime OrderDate;

   public decimal Freight;
}
```

And read the file in as this :

```
FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(Orders));

// to Read use:
Orders[] res = engine.ReadFile("TestIn.txt") as Orders[];

// to Write use:
engine.WriteFile("TestOut.txt", res);
```

You could change the delimiter to `" "` & suitably update the member types as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hey your code looks like there is an ID value at position one. So I created some example code.

```
private List<MyValues> Read(string fileName)
{
    var result = new List<MyValues>();
    var line = new string[] { };

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        while (sr.Peek() > -1)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine().Trim().Split(' ');

            var val = new MyValues();
            val.Id = Convert.ToInt32(line.ElementAt(0));

            for (int n = 1; n < line.Count(); n++)
            {
                val.Values.Add(Convert.ToDouble(line[n]));
            }

            result.Add(val);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

class MyValues
{
    public int Id = 0;
    public List<double> Values = new List<double>();
}
```